# Append data to datatable using Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The table displays 'No data available' but the data was appended inside the table 
[TableImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSGMP.png)[1]

this is my [firebaseimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJaVV.jpg)

here's my html code:

```
<div class="box box-success">
    <div class="box-header">
      <h3> Sales </h3> 
          <table id="orders" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Date Ordered</th>
                <th>Date Delivered</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="example">   
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

my javascript code:

```
 $('#orders').dataTable();
 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("sales/");
 rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
     var key = snap.key;
     var product = snap.child("product").val();
     var price = snap.child("price").val();
     var quantity = snap.child("quantity").val();
     var date_ordered = snap.child("date_ordered").val();
     var date_delivered = snap.child("date_delivered").val();

     $("#example").append("<tr id='" + key + "'><td>" + key + "</td><td>" +
         product + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + quantity + "</td><td>" +
         date_ordered + "</td><td>" + date_delivered + "</td><td>" +
         "<a href = 'product_list.html' > View < /a></td > < /tr>");
 });
```

can anyone help me? please .. :(

Comment: Can you please add an export of your database (in JSON) in order to see its structure?

Comment: i don't know how to add my json file here huhu :(

Comment: In the Firebase console, in the database part, on the top left corner you will find a three dots button --> click on Export JSON

Comment: Just edit your question and add it to it. You don't need to add the entire JSON (if it is too long), just a meaningful part that shows the data structure.

Comment: Done posting, thank you

Comment: Hhmmm.. could you please also post a print screen of your database from the Firebase console. Your JSON has a strange content ([ null, {..)

Answer (score 0):

I have a small improvement for your code, you can check it out below. I think you should try to make it works with raw HTML table first before using `dataTable` plugin. I don't know which dataTable plugin you're using but maybe you got 'No data available' because at the time you init the plugin, your table is empty.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("sales/");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
     var row = snap.val();
     var key = snap.key;
     var product = row.product;
     var price = row.price;
     var quantity = row.quantity;
     var date_ordered = row.date_ordered;
     var date_delivered = row.date_delivered;

     $("#example").append("<tr id='" + key + "'><td>" + key + "</td><td>" +
         product + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + quantity + "</td><td>" +
         date_ordered + "</td><td>" + date_delivered + "</td><td>" +
         "<a href = 'product_list.html' > View < /a></td > < /tr>");
 });
```

Comment: I used your code, but it still displays 'no data available', but thank you for responding and helping,  maybe i could just try to append it with other html tables as what you've said.